# How to delete data in relation to entities? | SLINGR

Tags: slingr

I want to achieve that if I delete a record of an entity, the records of entities that are related to it are also deleted. How could I do this? For example, I have a meeting system where reports are generated about the meeting. What I want is to delete the record of that meeting and that with it the report is also deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. One is automatic and another one is manual. I strongly recommend the automatic way except that you have any special needs.

The automatic way is by using the cascade options. Basically, in the relationship field, in the section `Type Rules` there is a sub-section called `Cascade Updates`. Here you will find the option `Delete Policy`, which should be set to `Delete Record`. For your case, I guess the report is pointing to the meeting, so in that field, you should set the setting mentioned before. This way, when a meeting is deleted, the report will be deleted as well.

The second option is to put a listener when a record of the meetings is deleted and manually find and delete all the reports associated to it. I guess something like this:

```
sys.data.delete('reports', {meeting: record.id()});
```

Comment: Trank you dgaviola